# Ubuntu 19.10 Intel Wireless AC 3160 working but Additional drivers said NO

Tags: drivers, 19.10, iwlwifi

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with an Intel AC Wireless dual-band 3160 wifi device, My Wifi is working fine but in the Software Center, in the additional driver's section the Ubuntu said *This device is not working* and only allow to select the *Do not use the device*.

My Wifi is Working fine and my Bluetooth too. I don't know why this message.

`dmesg` log

[image: dmesg log]

[image: Ubuntu Software Additional Drivers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any backports drivers for this device on Ubuntu 19.10.

Some backports were installed for a previous Ubuntu release that lacked kernel support of this device.

So leave it as is.

You can also remove Dell repository with this backport, not to confuse you in the future.

Comment: Thanks!, can you help me to remove the backport or at lease to identify it because in my list of the repository I don't see any related entry.

Comment: Post output of `dpkg -l | grep iwlwifi`

Comment: And also `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`