# Ubuntu 18.04 intel wireless ac 9260 "This device is not working" under additional drivers, but wifi is working

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, iwlwifi, firmware

I just did a fresh 18.04 install. Now my wifi isn't recognized for some reason, but I'm using wifi right now. I'm not sure what this means here's a screenshot of it.

[image]

I tried some possible solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083369/ubuntu-18-04-cannot-recognized-intel-wireless-ac-9260), but they didn't work for me. I also have windows 10 installed on the same laptop, but on another drive entirely. Also, worth mentioning is that I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed previous on the same laptop and I didn't have this problem before. Only after I tried doing a fresh install for the 3rd time (don't ask, I'm still learning) than I run into this issue.

I don't know if this is important, but after the install my system time was off by like 5hrs after I set the right time zones and everything. I had to go into bios and change the time and disable the automatic date & time settings for Ubuntu. Otherwise I wasn't even able to run Ubuntu updates because the time didn't match with the ubuntu servers. Anyway...

Here are some system specs:

```
Skynet:~$lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A 3
71:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0014]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Skynet:~$rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
Skynet:~$lspci | grep Network
71:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
Skynet:~$iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp113s0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"myFios-5.0GHz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 20:C0:47:E1:F4:FC   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:137   Missed beacon:0

enp110s0  no wireless extensions.
Skynet:~$modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-48.ucode
```

According to the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188752/ubuntu-19-10-intel-wireless-ac-3160-working-but-additional-drivers-said-no) it's ok to leave it as is, but I'm not entirely sure because as I mentioned before I had ubuntu working fine before and only after a fresh install I ran into this problem.
I would appreciate any help with this. I'm at a loss here, thank you.

Comment: It is OK to leave it as is. If your wireless is working correctly, there is no need to do anything at all.

Comment: yeah, it's working for now, but it doesn't make any sense why it says This device isn't working.

Comment: It's probably a bug in *Additional Drivers*.

Comment: it could be, but why didn't it show up originally? I never had this display in additional drivers tab before. The only thing that changed is that I did a reinstall of ubuntu. I've tried all of the install versions from 18.04.1 to 18.04.3 and I get the same thing. The only other thing I could think of is maybe there was a recent windows up date that is conflicting things in my system because I also run windows on a separate drive inside the same laptop, but I physically removed that drive and boot into ubuntu without any change in the additional drivers tab so idk...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mystery found, but not solved. This appears to be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1859308). If anyone else is having this problem, check it out at that link.

```
software-properties-gtk erroneously reports that certain Intel wireless adapter cards are not working
Bug #1859308 reported by Naël on 2020-01-12
Bug Description
On Ubuntu 20.04 (development branch), as of today, Additional Drivers (software-properties-gtk 0.98.6) reports that the device "Intel Corporation: Wireless-AC 9260" is not working, and suggests using a manually installed driver (cf. screenshot).

However the device is working correctly:

  * lsmod | grep iwlwifi, lspci -v, lshw, dmesg | grep iwlwifi all show
    that its driver iwlwifi is in use
  * ls /lib/firmware/*9260* show that the appropriate firmware files
    are present

And I am indeed writing this bug report connected to an ac (5 GHz) wifi network, where I can verify a ~130-160 Mbps download speed, so software-properties-gtk shouldn't report the device as not working and suggest manually installing a driver. Not sure why it says so?

EDIT: bug confirmed as affecting the following Intel wireless adapter cards, and assumedly more to come:

  Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200
  Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165
  Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
  Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
  Intel Wireless-AC 9260

Also for reference here are the specs of Intel adapter cards:

  ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html#@WirelessNetworking

ProblemType: Bug
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 20.04
Package: software-properties-gtk 0.98.6
ProcVersionSignature: Ubuntu 5.4.0-9.12-generic 5.4.3
Uname: Linux 5.4.0-9-generic x86_64
ApportVersion: 2.20.11-0ubuntu15
Architecture: amd64
CurrentDesktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Date: Sun Jan 12 00:53:43 2020
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk
InstallationDate: Installed on 2019-12-29 (13 days ago)
InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS "Focal Fossa" - Alpha amd64 (20191226)
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.7
PackageArchitecture: all
Python3Details: /usr/bin/python3.7, Python 3.7.6, python3-minimal, 3.7.5-1ubuntu1
PythonDetails: /usr/bin/python2.7, Python 2.7.17, python-minimal, 2.7.17-1
SourcePackage: software-properties
UpgradeStatus: No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)
```

Comment: That link appears to be broken - can you please update the question with a working link and ideally some info that doesn't rely on a link?

Comment: @Ross the link is working. I added the bug description also.